# paragraph tags in tweet field from web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I put together a quote machine as an exercise of freecodecamp.com. You click the button, you get a quote. Then, if you want, you can tweet the quote by clicking the "Tweet It" button. I had a lot of trouble figuring out how to get the quote to populate the tweet field. I finally just looked at someone else's code on the issue, and now it is populating.

The problem: it is populating `<p>` and `</p>` tags with every quote. Example:

> "`<p>`When typography is on point, words become images.`</p>`
>   " Shawn Lukas

It's also annoying that the second set of quotation marks always appears on the line below next to the author's name.

I'm not sure how the

tags are getting in there, but I'd like help clearing them out. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div id="quote" class="triangle-isosceles">
            <p>
                <span class="msg"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <p id="author"><span class="nme"></span></p>

    </div>

    <button type="button">Get Quote</button>
    <a class="twitter-share-button" id="tweet-quote" target="_blank">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tweet it!</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {

           var quote = a[0].content;
            var author = a[0].title;
            $(".msg").empty().append(quote + "<p>— " + author + "</p>")

        $('#tweet-quote').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text=' + encodeURIComponent('"' + quote + '" ' + author));
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm omitting the CSS. I can't get a jsfiddle to work (never can), but here's the CodePen link: https://codepen.io/dtarvin/pen/pePowj

Update: just found a quote with an apostrophe and got back those numbers instead of the symbol. Not sure how to handle that when the quotes are random.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have `"<p>— " + author + "</p>"` in the append code,  regarding the html entity code you need to parse the quote to switch them to the normal version.  Also you might need to remove tags within the `a[0].content` variable. if you have no control over what is returned, you may need to do a lot more filtering to catch stuff like this.

Or if you have access to the serverside script, then use this to get the quote and return the cleansed quote.

For instance, if you visit the url https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts you will see the `<p>` tags within the quote themselves.

So you basically need to clean the content of the `content` variable.

for instance to remvoe the `p` tag within the content string try:

`var quote = a[0].content.replace(/<p[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/<\/p>/g, '');`

If you need these tags in to display then you could add a seperate function that on pressing the tweet it button, will do this for you.

So you have them on the browser but on tweeting its all striped and good on twitter

Answer (score 0):

Try this it work

```
<script>
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });
        $('button').on('click', function() {
            $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {

               var quote = a[0].content;
                var author = a[0].title;
                $(".msg").empty().append(quote + author);

                var html = quote + author;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = html;
    var text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";

         $('#tweet-quote').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text=' + encodeURIComponent( text ));
            });
        });

</script>
```